# issue with Storing dictionary with key and multi values for key in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a loop on utterances(list of statements)

```
predicted_utt_label=defaultdict(list)
for utt in test_utterances:
         #here some code to detect label for each statement
```

Now I want to add utterance and its label in a dictionary and write the code here:

```
 predicted_utt_label[utt]=DA
```

But there is a problem with the statement like 'I don't know' and 'I don't know' with different labels like 'sd' and 'qy'. As both statements have different labels then how I can store them as statement key of dictionary and labels as multi value of that key? Because dictionary always have unique keys.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer your question, because there seems to be a lot of data missing (what is the 'utterance', what is 'DA', what is the label in this code?).  What I can say is that I think your line to add whatever it is to the dictionary should be: `predicted_utt_label[utt].append(DA)`

Comment: thank you. yes it works.

Comment: DA is actually dialogue act or label for utterance and utterance is like a complete sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a list as a key to each value will allow you to store multiple values to each key. Use a for loop to find the key needed and use another loop or even just a list comprehension to add the new value to this list of values. Let us know if this is of any help